# How to load signed applet from local disc with full permissions?

Tags: java, permissions, applet, signed, next-generation-plugin

I have an application where javascript code is accessing java applet methods that write on local disk (just to note - this is not directly possibly, but there is a workaround for it that enables to do so). Applet is self-signed applet, so users have to allow it to run first.

If applet's codebase is set to `"http://..."` everything works fine, in FF, Chrome and Opera as well. However, I would like to put this applet on local file system. However, if I use codebase `"file://..."` (I also tried to not use codebase at all and write directly full jar path to archive) it does not work, applet does not load with Warning-Security pop-up that enable user to allow running the applets.

I only tested it in FF (3.6.1.4) so far, Java version is 1.6.0.21.

Are signed applets limited only for HTTP use? Or is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1):

> ..is there some workaround?

Perhaps using the JNLP API services in an unsigned applet will work better.  I have a [demo. of the JNLP FileContents object](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

For details on using the JNLP services in an embedded applet see the links to the 'next generation plug-in' in the [applet information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) page.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunatelly, I would like it to run also on older versions of Java. If no other workarounf exists I will try it however.

So is it impossible to run signed applets from local drive?

Answer (score 1):

Applets loaded from the local filesystem are allowed to write files only in, or below, the directory containing the applet. So, if the applet is in `C:\MyProjects\MyAppletTest` it will be able to read and write files in that directory and its subdirectories, but not in `C:\MyProjects`. You can override this behavior with a policy files as explained in [Quick Tour of Controlling Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/index.html)